# Fuzzy matching JSON Part Schema matching getting failed

Tags: karate

I am trying to match the partial schema against a payload, but facing failures.

```
Given def payload =
"""
{
  "salesService": [
    {
      "name": "Test User",
      "username": "testuser",
      "email": "test@user.com",
      "address": {
        "doorNo": 32,
        "street": "Kenlab Clise",
        "landmark": true,
        "city": "Bracknell",
        "county": "Berkshire",
        "zipcode": "LI867H"
      }
    }
  ]
}
"""

* def schema =
"""
{
  "salesService": [
    {
      "name": "#string",
      "username": "#string",
      "email": "#present"
    }
  ]
}
"""

Then match payload contains schema
```

For the above mentioned payload and schema, currently I am facing the error(see below) which is quite logical, but is there any other way to match the above payload and partial schema without any errors?

Error:

`$.salesService[0] | not equal | actual has 1 more key(s) than expected - {"address":{"doorNo":2,"street":"Kenton Close","landmark":true,"city":"Bracknell","county":"Berkshire","zipcode":"RG129AZ"}} (MAP:MAP)       {"name":"Test User","username":"testuser","email":"test@user.com","address":{"doorNo":2,"street":"Kenton Close","landmark":true,"city":"Bracknell","county":"Berkshire","zipcode":"RG129AZ"}}       {"name":"#string","username":"#string","email":"#present"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
* match payload contains deep schema
```

Refer the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#match-contains-deep

Pay attention to where you have arrays etc. Also this would have worked:

```
* match each payload.salesService contains { "name": "#string", "username": "#string", "email": "#present" }
```